# IBMApplicationCenter.apk fails to install on Android 5.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have MobileFirst 7.1 installed and I downloaded the IBMApplicationCenter.apk onto Android 5.1 phone.  When I install it says "app not installed".
I set "allow unknown sources" and searched for any previous apps.  How else can I debug this .. or is this version of the apk too old ?

Comment: You are supposed to compile this apk yourself from the source project. Did you?

Answer (score 0):

From the phrasing of your question it does seem like you are using an incompatible version?

As part of the Application Center installation you have the AppCenter source - an Android project. You need to build that project into an .apk and you need to make sure that your development environment supports Android 5.1 - the configuration in AndroidManifest.xml.

What have you configured?